# I am not able to import AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I tried to import `AppCompatActivity` in android studio using code below

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

the word 'app' is highlighted in red and it give's me an error: that says

> "Cannot resolve symbol 'app'"

Anyone can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

try this in your `build.gradle (Module:app)`

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

or this (the same)

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```